# Do you/your company uses React Material-ui? why or why not?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, web-frontend

What are some of the reasons of you or your company choose to use Material-ui for React web apps.
Would like to know the reasons of why you use it or why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey DollyBeeBee Love that name Hahaha..

So.. Yes, we use it in some projects.

But the real question is.. Why not ?
Material-UI is awesome, and there a lot of nice components..

But, lets to pos and cons. .
beggining with cons, so the and can be happy ..

**Cons:**

- Somethimes is hard to stylize some components with its theme system, and a simple customization can be a little noisy..

**Pros:**

- A lot of rich components, beautiful interface, users love it, and still moderm.

Thats it!

Cheers! :D

Comment: Thankx @Jhony Spark. <3